# textview search multi words

Tags: swift, search, textview

if the user enters a word in the textview the code works, but if he writes more than one it doesn't work. How can I make the multi-word search work?

hello word IT DOES NOT WORK

hello OK WORK

world OK WORK

```
let userText = searchTextView.text // hello word
    
    let wordList = ["hello", "word"]
    
    let result = !wordList.contains(where: { !userText.contains($0) })
    
    print(result)
```

*** I solved the problem, here is the code ***

```
@IBAction func searchButton(_ sender: Any) {


        if searchTextView.text.count != 0 {

            let arraySearch = searchTextView.text.lowercased()

            let words = arraySearch.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

            for count in 0...words.count-1 {
                
            let resultWord = words[count]


            for str in dataTableWord {
                
            let arrayTableWord = str.word.lowercased()
            
            let range = arrayTableWord.range(of: resultWord)
     

            if range != nil {
                    dataSearch.append(str)
                }

                
            }
            
            
            }
            
            

            resultTableView.reloadData()
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: How should it work, match all words or some words? Did you try using a loop?

Comment: Do you want to check that each of the input contains all the words in ```wordList```?

Comment: If `userText` need to contains at least one from `wordList`, then `let result = wordList.contains(where: { userText.contains($0) })` should do the trick. If it's `userText` needs to contain ALL string in `wordList`, then `let result2 = wordList.allSatisfy({ userText.contains($0) })` should do the trick.

Comment: I would like the words that the user is looking for to come out of the database, if one writes one in the tableview, one record comes out, if two of them are written in the tableview, two records come out.

Comment: Thanks Larme, now I try your code

Comment: now it's a little better, but it still hasn't completely solved my problem

Comment: And what's your problem? Isn't one of my two solutions (depending on what you really need) working? What's your issue? Could you edit your question with your exact needs?

Comment: Ok, now i have updated the post.